# Android: switching from one layout activity to another

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I am trying to display a splash screen for 3 seconds and then go to the main screen, both of them being in the same class. However, my problem is that, when I try calling the new layout.activity, before the original layout.acitity for the class Im in, the program crash. Why?

Here is a little example of what I am talkin about:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);//new activity 
    displaySplash();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_visualizer);//original activity
```

The only way that I can get this to run is if I comment out the splash activity completely, but I need it! I wont work if I comment out the other layout activity...

Here are my two activities if it helps:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context="comp380.musicvisualizer.Visualizer" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/song_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context="comp380.musicvisualizer.Visualizer" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: I have also tried using the ViewFlipper, but still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be tempted to have both as fragments and switch between them.  However if you don't want to do that you could just have both the views in the same layout and change the visibility after three seconds.  Your view would be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context="comp380.musicvisualizer.Visualizer" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/song_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:visibility="gone" >
</ListView>
```

And then in the Activity do something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout); //the layout above

    displaySplash(); // I guess this waits three seconds

    // get refs to the views
    ImageView splashScreen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashscreen);
    ListView songList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.song_list);

    // swap the visibility
    splashScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    songList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the same layout for both of them and put them into FrameLayout, after 3 seconds hide the splash layout and show the normal layout?

You can also create two fragments, one SplashFragment and the other NomralFragment and just swap them after 3 secs if you really want to do this in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `setContentView()` twice for an `Activity`.

One possible solution would be to have the layout of the *splash screen* in the same place where your original activity is and manage its visibility.

Otherwise, you could have a *splash screen activity* with `R.layout.activity_splash` as layout and after 3 sec launch your *main activity*.

Comment: How would I do the firsts option? I have tried doing the second option, but my code still crashes...

Comment: please show us the crash log when you try the first option

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out my problem and you guys will never guess it: my code was failing because the picture I was using for my splash screen was way too big. I randomly changed the pic and everything works now...HUGE SIGH

Thank you all for trying though!